# This for loop isnt working and while i am trying to give values its not producing an output

Tags: r

I would like to know what I can correct in this code to get the desired
results.

```
  h1 <- function(x,n)
  Sum=0
   # this loop isn't working
   for (i  in seq(from=0,to=n)) {
   Sum = Sum + x^i
   }
  }
```

This is the output:

```
   h1(0.3,55)
   Error in h1(0.3, 55) 
   object 'Sum' not found
```

Comment: Your code is missing an opening brace.  Didn't you get syntax errors on lines 5 and 6?  If you didn't, then the code you posted is not what you were running.  If you did, you should fix those.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of mistakes in your code which has been solved in other answers. However, this can be solved without a loop.

```
h1 <- function(x,n) {
  sum(x^seq(from=0,to=n))
}
h1(0.3,55)
#[1] 1.428571
```

Answer (score 1):

A brace was missing:

```r
h1 <- function(x,n)
{ # this brace was missing
  Sum=0
  for (i  in seq(from=0,to=n)) {
    Sum = Sum + x^i
  }
  
  Sum
}

h1(0.3,55)
#> [1] 1.428571
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 <- function(x,n){
Sum=0
for (i  in seq(from=0,to=n)) {#.     ** This loop isnt working.** 
    Sum = Sum + x^i
}
  return(Sum)
}
h1(0.3,55)
1.428571
```